# Android to android TCP connection failed

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to make TCP connection between android phones which are in same subnet. Connection works when I use android phone as server and android emulator as client. But when I switch emulator to other android phone I get timeout. My android phones are in same local network(192.168.0.0/24).

Client script:

```
s = new Socket();
                s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IP, TCP_SERVER_PORT), 10000);

                DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                DOS.writeUTF("coord");

                s.close();
```

Server script:

```
 while(!end){
                        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                        Socket s = ss.accept();

                        DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                        String msg_received = DIS.readUTF();
                        Log.i("gauta",msg_received);

                        if(msg_received.equals("coord")) {

                            //some work.....

                        }

                        s.close();
                        if (quit){ end = true; }
                }
                ss.close();


                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Have you checked you have all permissions needed? Correct IP, etc. the standard-stuff?

Comment: Yes, internet permission is added to both manifests. I've checked few times, I use correct IP.

Comment: Oh...it seems everything works, second phone was having issues with wifi connection.